# Webpack ignores sass files

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using webpack for a project. It compiles the typescript fine, however, it seems to ignore the sass files. The sass files are stored in the './build/sass' of the project directory.

When running webpack the output is:

```
Hash: dc64dbebfd6ff9cb2a38
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 1201ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.7 kB       0  [emitted]  app
   [0] multi app 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden modules
```

So it runs fine. You can find the webpack.config.js below:

```
require('dotenv').load()

var webpack = require("webpack"),
    path = require('path'),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: [
            path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'js', 'app')
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
        root: path.join('.', 'build')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/,    loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.sass$/, loader: new ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass') },
            { loader: 'ts', test: /\.ts$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('public/main.css', {allChunks: true})
    ]
};
```

I've tried both with the ExtractTextPlugin and without. But it just looks like webpack is ignoring both sass and css files all toghether. I've looked at probably a dozens of examples, but no matter how I configure webpack it doesn't pick up sass or css files.

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
    "keystone": "^0.3.19",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "^2.10.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.2",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.8.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-config-keystone": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  }
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could shed some light about what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

I think I am right in saying that webpack builds up its bundle based on dependencies it finds in the code.

Do you require () your sass files anywhere?

(I would add this as a comment but I don't have that option yet)

Answer (score -1):

Really Webpack is used to bundle the JavaScript and not the CSS/SASS. You need to add a task to handle your SASS files. Here's something to get you started:

```
var config = require('../config');
if(!config.tasks.css) return;

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    path = require('path'),
    cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');

var paths = {
    src: path.join(config.root.src, config.tasks.css.src, '/**/*.{' + config.tasks.css.extensions + '}'),
    dest: path.join(config.root.dest, config.tasks.css.dest)
}

var cssTask = function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.src)
    .pipe(gulpif(!global.production, sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe(sass(config.tasks.css.sass))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(config.tasks.css.autoprefixer))
    .pipe(gulpif(global.production, cssnano({autoprefixer: false})))
    .pipe(gulpif(!global.production, sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
}

gulp.task('css', cssTask)
module.exports = cssTask
```

Then just add that to your production build task.

Comment: actually webpack is perfectly able to bundle css/ssas along with the javascript using the appropriate loaders.

Comment: This would require gulp as a dependency.

Comment: Lazy response make me give a upvote to this anwser. webpack is capable to handler with sass. Ex. sass-loader.